# How to match DB query result and API response directly in karate

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

My code is as follows =>
@UserValidationEmail

```
Feature: Verify User Details 

  Scenario: Verify User Details api

    Given url 'http://127.0.0.1/user/?id=123'
    When method get
    Then status 200

    * def DbUtils = Java.type('com.intuit.karate.treebo.util.DbUtils')
    * def db = new DbUtils()

    * def query = "SELECT * FROM user_table where id = 123"
    * def dbResult = db.readRows(query)


    * match dbResult[0] contains response.data
```

The response of the API call http://127.0.0.1/user/?id=123 is =>

```
{"status":"success","data":{"id":123,"created_at":"2018-01-18T10:27:24.631959","modified_at":"2018-01 18T10:27:24.641493","first_name":"Foo","last_name":"Bar","email":"foo@bar.com","phone_number":null}}
```

The response of the query on the DB is =>

```
[print] dbResult: [{id=123, password=bZeGU3h66cp, created_at=2018-01-18 15:57:24.631959, modified_at=2018-01-18 15:57:24.641493, first_name=Foo, last_name=Bar, email=foo@bar.com, phone_number=null}]
```

On trying to match the above two results using contains, I get the following error:

```
Tests in error: 
  * match dbResult[0] contains response.data(Scenario: Verify User Details api): path: $[0].created_at, actual: 2018-01-18 15:57:24.631959, expected: '2018-01-18T10:27:24.631959', reason: actual value is not a string
```

Ho can I match the result of the DB query directly to the API response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the message:

```
path: $[0].created_at, actual: 2018-01-18 15:57:24.631959, expected: '2018-01-18T10:27:24.631959'
reason: actual value is not a string
```

Clearly the result-row returned has a `java.util.Date` or similar, instead of a string. even if it was a string, note that the values are not the same.

Either convert that field to a string and compare. Or most likely this will work for you - just do this before the comparison:

```
* set response.data.created_at = '#ignore'
```

Read the docs on fuzzy-matching if you need to understand this more: https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching